# Establishing TLS with the service based on the hostname

Tags: asp.net, ssl, networking

let's say a client can communicate with services A, B or C which are sitting behind a proxy (l4).

The client sends a stream of data over TCP to the proxy which in turn is responsible for forwarding the call to the required service as a TCP stream.

Because of some error at the required service, let's say at A, the proxy forwards this request to the error handler and mentions in the header the service name A. Now the error handler establishes the TLS by presenting the certificates of A and sending back the HTTPS response

After some time, an error occurred at service B, thus proxy decides to again send the TCP buffer to the error handler and then B would establish the TLS with the client with the help of the certificates of B.

I'm having trouble regarding how to establish a TLS between a client and the error handler service every time depending on the service name.

Reason of not doing this TLS at the proxy in because our design is to only route the incoming TCP buffer. We also have to run complex sophisticated work on this error handler service. Hence, we don't want to do the same on proxy.

Comment: *"The client makes a TCP request"* - there is no such thing as a TCP request - TCP just provides an unstructured byte stream without any inherent semantics. There is also no forwarding in TCP. And with just having a TCP connection established the intended hostname is only known to the client, not the server.

Comment: By TCP request I meant the  stream of byte is send from the client to the proxy over l4 connection.

Comment: A proxy terminates TCP connections. The proxy stands in for the server and terminates the client connection, it also stands in for the client an creates a connection to the server. The client thinks the proxy is the server, and the server thinks the proxy is the client. The proxy maintains two connections for the logical connection between client and server. TLS will also need to terminate the same way as TCP since it depends on the TCP connection, and the proxy must see inside the encrypted content.

Comment: @RonMaupin thanks for the input.  Existing architecture doesn't terminate the TCP at the proxy, the proxy just forwards the stream of the data to the required service which would, in turn, establish the TLS.  Our requirement is that if the proxy finds out that the service is down, it would forward the request to the error handler service.

Comment: That is not a proxy. A proxy is literally something that represents something else. You seen to mean a server also serving as a router that forwards packets between networks, but a proxy pretends it is a server to the client and a client to the server, standing in for each.

Comment: @RonMaupin, yes it is actually a web server that just forwards the TCP buffer. My bad for calling it a proxy.